# Comparing two dates with twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am currently working on an active user overview page and it was all running smoothly until I was asked to provide a "last activity column". It all functions well using just the date, but the data displayed should be in the form of "last active ... minutes ago".
Now the problem that I´m facing is that I have the code running and I can not seem to find a way to subtract the lastActivityTime from the currentTime and format it to display it.

```
{% if activeRegularUsers|length > 0 %}
    {% for regularUser in activeRegularUsers %}
    <tbody>
        <tr class="_recolor" id="tableTile">
            <td class="uidCell" id="tableTile">{{ regularUser.uid }}</td>
            <td class="firstNameCell" id="tableTile">{{ regularUser.firstName }}</td>
            <td class="familyNameCell" id="tableTile">{{ regularUser.familyName }}</td>
            <td class="unitCell" id="tableTile">{{ regularUser.readableStateName }}</td>
            <td class="stateCell" id="tableTile">{{ (dateToday - regularUser.LastActivityAt)|date('H:i:s Y-m-d') }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <tbody>
        <td colspan="5" class="_recolor">Keine eingeloggten Benutzer in dieser Benutzergruppe.</td>
    </tbody>
{% endif %}
```

It can be seen in the last  under the first .

I´ve tried to format with .format('H:i:s Y-m-d') as well as |date and formatting both dateToday and LastactivityAt but nothing seems to work.

I would appreciate a lead on this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey, you can follow this URL for more detail, http://qpleple.com/compare-dates-with-twig/

Comment: You can't run arbitrary PHP code in Twig.  The easiest approach is to add a new method to your regular user entity.  Or else create a twig extension.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I will try to use a method next, I was just wondering if it would be possible with twig and you solved this for me. Appreciate your answers :)